# Android binding not working with fragments

Tags: android, binding, fragment

I'm following the official documentation on how to do the binding, but no success with the fragments. The app receives data from a server and displays it in different views in a fragment, but nothing is rendered. The data arrives from the server successfully, but is not displayed. There are no errors or exceptions.

```
class DashboardFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_dashboard) {

    private val dashboardViewModel: DashboardViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private var isAffiliateContactInfoDialogShown = false

    private var _fragmentDashboardBinding: FragmentDashboardBinding? = null
    private var _generalStatsBinding: LayoutGeneralStatsBinding? = null
    private var _fragmentSurveyBinding: FragmentSurveyResultsStatsBinding? = null

    private val fragmentDashboardBinding get() = _fragmentDashboardBinding!!
    private val generalStatsBinding get() = _generalStatsBinding!!
    private val fragmentSurveyBinding get() = _fragmentSurveyBinding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _fragmentDashboardBinding = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        _generalStatsBinding = LayoutGeneralStatsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        _fragmentSurveyBinding = FragmentSurveyResultsStatsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return fragmentDashboardBinding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        fragmentDashboardBinding.currencyOfValuesTextView.text = getString(R.string.tdband_values_currency)
        checkForRequiredActions()
        dashboardViewModel.generalStats.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            showGeneralStats(it.asAffiliateGeneralStats())
        }
        dashboardViewModel.projectsSurveyStats.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            Timber.i("projectsSurveyStats: $it")
            fragmentDashboardBinding.surveyResultsTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(fragmentDashboardBinding.surveyResultsViewPager.apply {
                adapter = SurveysStatsPagerAdapter(context, it,  fragmentSurveyBinding)
                // TODO fix create new if exist
            })
        }

        dashboardViewModel.user.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { if (it != null) dashboardViewModel.refreshData() }

        fragmentDashboardBinding.swipeToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener {
            dashboardViewModel.refreshData()
            fragmentDashboardBinding.swipeToRefresh.isRefreshing = false
        }

        fragmentDashboardBinding.myLeadsButton.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_dashboardFragment_to_myLeadsFragment)
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        hideActionBar()
        showBottomNavigation()
        hideAnimation()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _fragmentDashboardBinding = null
        _generalStatsBinding = null
        _fragmentSurveyBinding = null
    }

    private fun showGeneralStats(generalStats: AffiliateGeneralStats) {
        generalStats.earned.toString().apply {
            generalStatsBinding.dashboardTotalEarnedValue.text = split(".")[0].decimalThousandSeparator()
            generalStatsBinding.dashboardTotalEarnedFractionalPart.text = split(".")[1].fractionPart()
        }
        generalStats.reported.toString().apply {
            generalStatsBinding.dashboardReportedValue.text = split(".")[0].decimalThousandSeparator()
            generalStatsBinding.dashboardReportedFractionalPart.text = split(".")[1].fractionPart()
        }
        generalStats.paid.toString().apply {
             generalStatsBinding.dashboardTotalPaidValue.text = split(".")[0].decimalThousandSeparator()
            generalStatsBinding.dashboardTotalPaidFractionalPart.text = split(".")[1].fractionPart()
        }
    }

    private fun checkForRequiredActions() {
        dashboardViewModel.affiliate.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { affiliate ->
            affiliate?.let {
                if (it.requiredActions.contains(AffiliateRequiredActions.UPDATE_PROFILE.type)) {
                    showAffiliateContactDialog(affiliate.contact)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun showAffiliateContactDialog(contact: AffiliateContact?) {
        val dialog = AffiliateContactInfoDialog(requireContext(), viewLifecycleOwner, contact)
        dialog.setOnShowListener {
            isAffiliateContactInfoDialogShown = true
        }
        if (!isAffiliateContactInfoDialogShown) {
            dialog.show()
            dialog.setAffiliateContactInfoCallBack(object :
                AffiliateContactInfoCallBack {
                override fun onRequestDataUpdate(name: String, phone: String) {
                    lifecycleScope.launch {
                        dashboardViewModel.updateAffiliateContact(
                            name = name,
                            phone = phone
                        ).observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { exception ->
                            if (exception == null) {
                                dialog.dismiss()
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    requireContext(),
                                    R.string.tdband_update_contact_info_failed,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                ).show()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }

    private fun String.decimalThousandSeparator(): String =
        if (length < 3) {
            this
        } else {
            StringBuilder(this).insert(length - 3, " ").toString()
        }

    private fun String.fractionPart(): String = if (length < 2) {
        this + "0"
    } else {
        this.substring(0, 2)
    }
}

class SurveysStatsPagerAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val surveysStats: List<SurveyResultsStats>,
    private val fragmentSurveyBinding: FragmentSurveyResultsStatsBinding
) : PagerAdapter() {

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence = when (position) {
        0 -> context.getString(R.string.tdband_leads)
        1 -> context.getString(R.string.tdband_deals)
        else -> context.getString(R.string.tdband_leads)
    }

    override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
        container.removeView(`object` as View)
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return surveysStats.size
    }

    override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, `object`: Any): Boolean {
        return view === `object`
    }

    override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_survey_results_stats,
                container,
                false
            ) as ViewGroup

        val surveyStats = surveysStats[position]

        fragmentSurveyBinding.dashboardLinksClicksValue.text = surveyStats.linksClicks?.toString() ?: "0"
        fragmentSurveyBinding.dashboardLeadAcceptedValue.text = surveyStats.accepted?.toString() ?: "0"
        fragmentSurveyBinding.dashboardLeadAcceptedLabel.text = context.getString(
            if (position == 1) R.string.tdband_deals_won else R.string.tdband_leads_accepted
        )
        fragmentSurveyBinding.dashboardLeadsGeneratedValue.text = surveyStats.generated?.toString() ?: "0"
        fragmentSurveyBinding.dashboardLeadsReportedValue.text = surveyStats.reported?.toString() ?: "0"

        container.addView(view)
        return view
    }
}
```

I followed the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding